# Uso de " for x in range (n,m) "

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy diseñando un programa en python para calcular la sumatoria desde n hasta m de i, y para ello estoy usando " for x in range (n,m) ".

```
print("Este programa calcula la sumatoria desde n hasta m de i.\n\nA 
continuación ingrese los límites:")
print("")

n = int(input("Ingrese un valor para el límite inferior (n):"))
m = int(input("Ingrese un valor para el límite superior (m):"))

if n < m:
   for x in range(n,m):
      sumatoria = n + x:
   print ("el valor de la sumatoria es " + str(sumatoria))
else:
   print("el límite superior debe ser mayor que el inferior.")
```

Al parecer hay un problema con n y x ya que aparece syntax error. 
¿Podría alguien explicarme qué está fallando?.

Gracias.

Comment: no sé de python pero talves podrias poner un for individual dentro de otro for

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so] Michaelhper. Te recomiendo que te mires [ask]  y [tour] para ver como realizar buenas preguntas y el funcionamiento general del sitio. Es recomendable que en estos casos agregues el error que te lanza para facilitar el trabajo de posibles usuarios que quieran responderte.  Lo primero que tienes es un error tipográfico,  en `sumatoria = n + x:` sobran los dos puntos finales. ¿Lo que quieres es sumar los números enteros entre `n` y `m`?, ¿se incluyen `m` y `n` en la suma?  Debes declarar `sumatoria` fuera del `for` e incrementar su valor en él...

Answer (score 2):

La verdad es que tu código tienes varios errores pero te ayudo a arreglarlos.

En esta primera línea tienes un salto de carro que deberías eliminar:

```
print("Este programa calcula la sumatoria desde n hasta m de i.\n\nA 
continuación ingrese los límites:")
```

Por otro lado tienes dos puntos al final de esta línea que causan tu error sintáctico

```
sumatoria = n + x:
```

Para finalizar, tu código no hace lo que pretendes ya que sobrescribes el valor de la variable *sumatoria* en vez de incrementarla. Para que haga lo que deseas, debes hacer lo siguiente dentro de tu **if**:

```
sumatoria = 0
for x in range(n,m+1):
   sumatoria = sumatoria + x
print ("el valor de la sumatoria es " + str(sumatoria))
```

Como puedes ver, sumo 1 a la m dentro de la función range ya que esta no incluye el límite superior que entiendo que necesitas. Es decir, el siguiente código:

```
range(1,5)
```

daria como resultado:

```
[1,2,3,4]
```

Saludos y espero que te haya servido mi respuesta.